# Create 2D numpy array with append function

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a 2D numpy array of dimensions Nx2, in python. I want to create this by using 2 `for` loops. I can easily build this array in Matlab with the following code

```
matrix = [];

for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:4
        temp = [i, j];
        matrix = [matrix; temp];
    end
end
```

I have tried already numerous times, but failed. Usually, the error that I get is related to the sizes of arrays not matching when I run the `for` loops.

The output of the code is

```
matrix =

 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 2     1
 2     2
 2     3
 2     4
 3     1
 3     2
 3     3
 3     4
```

Comment: `np.zeros((100,100))` create a 2-D array filled with zeros. It would be clear if you add expected output to the question.

Comment: You are right, I am going to add the expected output. What you mentioned might be the first step. Thank you

Comment: Remember in MATLAB everything is 2d.  The `[]` is 0x0; `[[]; [1,2]]` joins that with a 1x2,expanding shapes as needed.  In `numpy` arrays may be 0d,1d etc.  `np.concatenate` is picky about matching dimensions.  `np.append` is a poorly conceived front end to `concatenate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that does what you want and uses two for loops. The reason that N is +1 and M is +1 is because in python the range() function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from 0 by default, and increments by 1 (by default), and ends at a specified number. So since we are starting at 1 instead of 0 we need to add 1 so that the actual range is correct. ie. 0,4 is a range of 4, but 1,4 is only really a range of 3. Hope that helps! -Brack

```
import numpy as np


def Nx2(N, M):
    matrix=[]
    n = N+ 1
    m= M + 1
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(1,m):
            temp=[i,j]
            matrix.append(temp)
    final_matrix = np.array(matrix)
    return final_matrix
print(Nx2(3, 4))
```

Comment: You're setting a global matrix outside the function (bad), but then returning it (good).

Comment: Also, this is not materially different from the answer posted by SurajSubramanian a quarter hour earlier.

Comment: In this instance, is it better to put the matrix=[] inside of the function? (always learning)

Comment: Absolutely. It's simply wrong not to. Try running your function twice.

Comment: As a rule, mutable globals are bad. Use input parameters and return values, avoid globals.

Comment: Oh wow I see what you are saying now. Thank you for clearing that up for me! I appreciate it. Its always nice to try to help someone and end up learning something myself in the process

Comment: It's nice to have those moments. By the way, don't forget to fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

```py
matrix= []

for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1,5):
        temp= [i,j]
        matrix.append(temp)
```

Finally you can convert the list of lists into a numpy array using 
`matrix = np.array(matrix)`

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need a loop in either MATLAB or numpy for this. In both languages, explicit loops tend to be slow compared to the under-the-hood loops that run when you vectorize code. The additional problem with appending inside a loop is that each operation re-allocates the entire array to add the new element. You want to avoid appending and pre-allocate as much as possible.

Both packages have a `meshgrid` function. In numpy you could do:

```
ii = np.arange(3) + 1
jj = np.arange(4) + 1
j, i = np.meshgrid(jj, ii)

matrix = np.stack((i.ravel(), j.ravel()), axis=1)
```

In MATLAB, it would be very similar:

```
ii = 1:3;
jj = 1:4;
[i, j] = meshgrid(ii, jj);

matrix = [i(:) j(:)];
```

If you absolutely need to do this in a loop with constant reallocation, the MATLAB loop translates to numpy very easily. Instead of doing implicit `vertcat`, use `np.append`, or `np.concatenate`:

```
matrix = np.array((0, 2));

for i in range(1, 4)
    for j in range(1, 5)
        temp = [[i, j]]
        matrix = np.append(matrix, temp, axis=0)
```

Comment: I understand that with 'for' loops it is inefficient. I understand that I might be creating a bad habit, but the data dimensions that I am managing is not large, so it does not matter. The last piece of code you have put is what I have been trying to do. I get the following error, as I have so far.    ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)